# How to align the numbers properly?

Tags: c

I have tried using `%-20s` and `\t` but it wont give me the correct result, I am taking input from a file. I want all the 0's aligned correctly.

Here is my `printf` statement:

```
printf("%2d. %-20s%-20s %20d %7d %7d %7d\n", n + 1,
           unit[n].name,
           unit[n].muscles,
           unit[n].weight,
           unit[n].time,
           unit[n].sets,
           unit[n].reps);
```

This is my output:

[image: I want the 0's of exercise 2 to be aligned properly]

Comment: The `20` in the second `%-20s` is too low, you have a longer string than that, use a bigger number.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for the reply I'll try that, thanks for the edit, I was in the process of editing as well, I am new here

Comment: No problem. It would be better if you added the output as a block of code though, using images is discouraged.

Comment: I did not know that, would keep that in mind. Thank you. Also, I incread the spacing by 10 and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `%-20.20s` to limit the string to 20 characters.  The extra will be truncated.

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer so that you can mark your question as solved if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `20` in the second `%-20s` in your format string is too low, you have a longer string than that. You must use a bigger number in order for it to be correctly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than guess at the needed size, use variable width and let code do the calculation.

```
int m_width = 1;
for (n=0; n<N; n++) {
  int len = strlen(unit[n].muscles);
  if (len >m_width) {
    m_width = len;
  }
}
...

//                  v-- width
printf("%2d. %-20s%-*s %20d %7d %7d %7d\n", n + 1,
       unit[n].name,
       m_width, unit[n].muscles,
       unit[n].weight,
       unit[n].time,
       unit[n].sets,
       unit[n].reps);
```

Likewise for other memebrs..